# how to insert something in the beginning of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html like this:

```
<div id="leftBar">
<span>ad</span>
</div>
```

Also I have this variable:

```
var msg = '<span>something</span>';
```

I want to push `msg` variable in the beginning of `#leftBar` element. How can I do that?

This is expected result:

```
<div id="leftBar">
<span>something</span>
<span>ad</span>
</div>
```

---

Noted that `.html()` won't work as expected. Because `$('#leftBar').html(msg);` removes the existing `<span>` which I need to keep it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `prepend()` method  is the solution. `append()` method is similar in nature, but it adds the element as the last element.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript provides [Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method

You can try this:

```
var left = document.getElementById('leftBar')
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML = "something"

left.insertBefore(span, left.childNodes[0]);
```

jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/occtsyjv/)

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add new element from beginning(as first child).

```js
var msg = '<span>something</span>';
$('#leftBar').prepend(msg)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="leftBar">
<span>ad</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
leftBar.innerHTML=msg+leftBar.innerHTML;
```

try a demo : [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n63q3p0k/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var msg = '<span>something</span><br>'; // Your variable -- but i added '<br>' --
 $('button[rel="add"]').click(function() {
   $('#leftBar').append( msg ); // For add after last element within #leftBar
    //$('#leftBar').append( msg ); // For add before first element within #leftBar
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="leftBar">
  <span>ad</span>
  <br>
</div>

<button rel="add">Add +</button>
```